# Autoplay function Infiniteslider JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, infinite-loop, uislider

Stuck with a fiddly (for me) bit of JS for my infinite slider. I'm trying to use the set interval function to auto click through the slides however I haven't been able to identify the correct function in the JS.

I know I need to replace the alert with said function but don't know what that would be to click through slides.Any idea?

```
    window.setInterval(yourfunction, 10000);
    function yourfunction() { alert('test'); }
```

Slider JS:

```
    function InfiniteSlider(wrapper,speed,duration,mode,easing,hover,animation){
var _infiniteSlider = this;

// If true : running
this.animated = false;
// Autorotation
this.hover = hover;
this.autorotation = animation;
this.running = true;
this.t;
// Setting the container and controller
this.wrapper = $(wrapper);
this.container = $('.slider',this.wrapper);
this.arrows = $('.slider-arrows',this.wrapper);
this.count = $('.count',this.arrows);
this.controls = $('.slider-controls',this.wrapper);
this.infos = $('.slider-infos',this.wrapper);
this.speed = speed;
this.duration = duration;
this.mode = mode; // slide - slidev - fade - demask
this.easing = easing;
this.width = this.container.width();
this.height = this.container.height();
// Setting index : slide ordered index || indexSlide : slide real index
this.index = 0;
this.indexSlide = 0;
// Number of elements
this.length = $('li', this.container).length - 1;

/* Initialize
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// */

// Bind
if(this.hover){
    $(this.wrapper).live('mouseenter', function(){
        _infiniteSlider.stop(_infiniteSlider);
    });
    $(this.wrapper).live('mouseleave', function(){
        _infiniteSlider.start(_infiniteSlider);
    });
}

$('.next a',this.arrows).live('click', function(){
    _infiniteSlider.next(_infiniteSlider);
    return false;
});
$('.previous a',this.arrows).live('click', function(){
    _infiniteSlider.previous(_infiniteSlider);
    return false;
});
$('li a',this.controls).live('click', function(){
    _infiniteSlider.controlsClick($(this),_infiniteSlider);
    return false;
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    _infiniteSlider.reset(_infiniteSlider);
});

// Identify each slide and control with initial order
$('li', this.container).each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-slide',$(this).index() + 1);

    if($(this).index() == 0){
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(_infiniteSlider.controls).append('<li data-slide="'+($(this).index()    + 1)+'" class="active"><a href=""><span>'+$(this).index()+'</span></a></li>');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('inactive');
        $(_infiniteSlider.controls).append('<li data-slide="'+($(this).index() + 1)+'" class="inactive"><a href=""><span>'+$(this).index()+'</span></a></li>');
    } 
});

// Fill Count values
$(this.count).html((this.index + 1)+' / '+(this.length + 1));

// Fill First Infos
if($('li:eq(0)', this.container).attr('data-infos') != '') $(this.infos).html($('li:eq(0)', this.container).attr('data-infos'));

// Disable if just one slide
if(this.length == 0){
    $(this.controls).hide();
    this.autorotation = false;
}

// Initiate Positioning
this.reset(_infiniteSlider);

// Start Autorotation
if(this.running) this.autoRotation(_infiniteSlider);
    }

    /* ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Autorotation
    //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// */

    InfiniteSlider.prototype.autoRotation = function(_infiniteSlider){
clearTimeout(_infiniteSlider.t);    

if($('li', _infiniteSlider.controls).length > 1 && _infiniteSlider.autorotation){
    if(_infiniteSlider.running){
        _infiniteSlider.t = setTimeout(function(){
                    _infiniteSlider.changeSlide(_infiniteSlider.indexSlide,_infiniteSlider.indexSlide +         1,_infiniteSlider)
        },_infiniteSlider.duration);
            }
        }
    }

    /* ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // External Functions
    //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// */

    InfiniteSlider.prototype.start = function(_infiniteSlider){ 
_infiniteSlider.running = true;
_infiniteSlider.autoRotation(_infiniteSlider);

return false;
    }

    InfiniteSlider.prototype.stop = function(_infiniteSlider){ 
clearTimeout(_infiniteSlider.t); 
_infiniteSlider.running = false; 

return false;
    }

    InfiniteSlider.prototype.next = function(_infiniteSlider){
if(!_infiniteSlider.animated){
    _infiniteSlider.autorotation = false;
    clearTimeout(_infiniteSlider.t);
            _infiniteSlider.changeSlide(_infiniteSlider.indexSlide,_infiniteSlider.indexSlide +         1,_infiniteSlider);
}

return false;
    }

    InfiniteSlider.prototype.previous = function(_infiniteSlider){
if(!_infiniteSlider.animated){
    _infiniteSlider.autorotation = false;
    clearTimeout(_infiniteSlider.t);
    _infiniteSlider.changeSlide(_infiniteSlider.indexSlide,_infiniteSlider.indexSlide - 1,_infiniteSlider);
}

return false;
    }

    InfiniteSlider.prototype.controlsClick = function(object,_infiniteSlider){
if(!_infiniteSlider.animated){
    _infiniteSlider.autorotation = false;
    // Stop timer
    clearTimeout(_infiniteSlider.t);

    var clicked = $(object).parent().index();

    $('li',_infiniteSlider.container).each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('data-slide') == clicked + 1){
            _infiniteSlider.changeSlide(_infiniteSlider.indexSlide,$(this).index(),_infiniteSlider);
        } 
    }); 
}

return false;
    }

    InfiniteSlider.prototype.reset = function(_infiniteSlider){
_infiniteSlider.wrapper.height($(window).height());
$('.centered-v', _infiniteSlider.wrapper).css('top', ($('.slider-alt-nav', _infiniteSlider.wrapper).height()/2 - $('.centered-v', _infiniteSlider.wrapper).height()/2)+'px');

_infiniteSlider.stop(_infiniteSlider);
_infiniteSlider.width = _infiniteSlider.container.width();
_infiniteSlider.height = _infiniteSlider.container.height();
$('li',_infiniteSlider.container).width(_infiniteSlider.width);

if(_infiniteSlider.mode == 'demask'){
    $('li.inactive',_infiniteSlider.container).width(0);
    $('li img',_infiniteSlider.container).width(_infiniteSlider.width);
}

// Adjust Arrows
$(_infiniteSlider.arrows).css('top', ($(_infiniteSlider.container).height()/2 - $('a',_infiniteSlider.arrows).height()/2)+'px');
// Adjust Images Size
$('li img',_infiniteSlider.container).each(function(){
    // Ratios
    var imageRatio = 1600/935;
    var wrapperRatio = _infiniteSlider.width/_infiniteSlider.height;

    // Resize
    if(imageRatio > wrapperRatio){
        $(this)
            .height(_infiniteSlider.height)
            .width(_infiniteSlider.height * imageRatio)
            .css('margin-left',-($(this).width()/2 - _infiniteSlider.width/2)+'px')
            .css('margin-top','0');
    } else {
        $(this)
            .width(_infiniteSlider.width)
            .height(_infiniteSlider.width / imageRatio)
            .css('margin-left','0')
            .css('margin-top',-($(this).height()/2 - _infiniteSlider.height/2)+'px');
    }
});

_infiniteSlider.start(_infiniteSlider); 

return false;
    }

    /* ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Change slide
    //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// */

    InfiniteSlider.prototype.changeSlide = function(current,clicked,_infiniteSlider){           
_infiniteSlider.animated = true;
var direction = 'next';
if(clicked < current) direction = 'previous';

// Check limits
if(clicked > _infiniteSlider.length){
    clicked = 0;
} else if(clicked < 0){
    clicked = _infiniteSlider.length;
}

// Redefine active slide
$('> ul > li',_infiniteSlider.container).removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
$('> ul > li',_infiniteSlider.container).eq(clicked).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');

_infiniteSlider.index = parseInt($('.active',_infiniteSlider.container).attr('data-slide')) - 1;
_infiniteSlider.indexSlide = $('.active',_infiniteSlider.container).index();

// Redefine active control
$('li',_infiniteSlider.controls).removeClass('active');
$('li',_infiniteSlider.controls).eq(_infiniteSlider.index).addClass('active');

// Change Count
$(_infiniteSlider.count).html($('.active',_infiniteSlider.container).attr('data-slide')+' / '+(_infiniteSlider.length + 1));

// Animate Infos
$(_infiniteSlider.infos).fadeOut(_infiniteSlider.speed/2, function(){
    if(typeof $('li.active',_infiniteSlider.container).attr('data-infos') !== "undefined"){
        $(_infiniteSlider.infos).html($('li.active',_infiniteSlider.container).attr('data-infos'));
        $(this).fadeIn(_infiniteSlider.speed/2);
    } else {
        $(_infiniteSlider.infos).html('');
    }
});

// Animate Slides
if(_infiniteSlider.mode == 'slide'){
    // Place new slide AFTER
    if(direction == 'next'){
        $('li',_infiniteSlider.container).eq(clicked)
            .css('left', _infiniteSlider.width+'px')
            .show();

        // Animate slides
        $('li',_infiniteSlider.container).animate({left: '-='+_infiniteSlider.width}, {'duration': _infiniteSlider.speed, easing: _infiniteSlider.easing, 'complete': function(){               
            _infiniteSlider.animated = false;
            $('li.inactive',_infiniteSlider.container).hide();
            if(_infiniteSlider.running) _infiniteSlider.autoRotation(_infiniteSlider);
        }});
    }
    // Place new slide BEFORE
    else {
        $('li',_infiniteSlider.container).eq(clicked)
            .css('left', -_infiniteSlider.width+'px')
            .show();

        // Animate slides
        $('li',_infiniteSlider.container).animate({left: '+='+_infiniteSlider.width}, {'duration': _infiniteSlider.speed, easing: _infiniteSlider.easing, 'complete': function(){               
            _infiniteSlider.animated = false;
            $('li.inactive',_infiniteSlider.container).hide();
            if(_infiniteSlider.running) _infiniteSlider.autoRotation(_infiniteSlider);
        }});
    }
}   else if(_infiniteSlider.mode == 'slidev'){
    // Place new slide AFTER
    if(direction == 'next'){
        $('li',_infiniteSlider.container).eq(clicked)
            .css('top', _infiniteSlider.height+'px')
            .show();

        // Animate slides
        $('li',_infiniteSlider.container).animate({top: '-='+_infiniteSlider.height}, {'duration': _infiniteSlider.speed, easing: _infiniteSlider.easing, 'complete': function(){               
            _infiniteSlider.animated = false;
            $('li.inactive',_infiniteSlider.container).hide();
            if(_infiniteSlider.running) _infiniteSlider.autoRotation(_infiniteSlider);
        }});
    }
    // Place new slide BEFORE
    else {
        $('li',_infiniteSlider.container).eq(clicked)
            .css('top', -_infiniteSlider.height+'px')
            .show();

        // Animate slides
        $('li',_infiniteSlider.container).animate({top: '+='+_infiniteSlider.height}, {'duration': _infiniteSlider.speed, easing: _infiniteSlider.easing, 'complete': function(){               
            _infiniteSlider.animated = false;
            $('li.inactive',_infiniteSlider.container).hide();
            if(_infiniteSlider.running) _infiniteSlider.autoRotation(_infiniteSlider);
        }});
    }
} else if(_infiniteSlider.mode == 'fade'){
    // Animate Slides
    $('> ul > li.active',_infiniteSlider.container).fadeIn(_infiniteSlider.speed, function(){
        $('> ul > li',_infiniteSlider.container).eq(current).hide();
        _infiniteSlider.animated = false;
        if(_infiniteSlider.running) _infiniteSlider.autoRotation(_infiniteSlider);
    });
} else if(_infiniteSlider.mode == 'demask'){
    $('> ul > li.active',_infiniteSlider.container).animate({width: _infiniteSlider.width}, _infiniteSlider.speed, _infiniteSlider.easing, function(){
        $('> ul > li.inactive',_infiniteSlider.container).width(0);
        _infiniteSlider.animated = false;
        if(_infiniteSlider.running) _infiniteSlider.autoRotation(_infiniteSlider);
    });
}

    }
```

Thanks for any help :)

Miles

Answer (score 0):

I've never used JQuery but as a guess why not try

```
function yourfunction() {_infiniteSlider.next(_infiniteSlider);
return false;}
```

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for this however it doesn't seem to work for me, I'm not sure why. Does the .next extension also act as the clicking function or are they 2 separate pieces of info? Ie. do I need to add 'click' somewhere to that? Cheers - Miles

Comment: Hmmm. I googled around. Try looking at this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068652/jquery-slider-with-controls-and-automatic-scrolling

I think it does what you want and has working code.

Comment: That is a nice and simple code for a slider which does work - thanks. I'm still trying to resurrect this one, mind, as it has an elegant fade as opposed to slide action. I'm still looking. Think it will be something to do with this once I work it out: window.setInterval( yourfunction, 10000); 
function yourfunction() {click('_infiniteSlider.next',_infiniteSlider);
return false;}